# browserify-shader transform sourcemap issues

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

I have something like this

```js
var bundler = browserify('./www/js/app/main.js', {
    debug: true
});

if (watch) {
    bundler = watchify(bundler);
    bundler.on('update', function(){ bundle(bundler) });
    bundler.on('log', function(message){ $.util.log(message) });
}

bundler.transform(
    babelify.configure({
        sourceMapRelative: 'www/js',
        presets: ['es2015'],
        plugins: ['transform-class-properties']
    })
);

bundler.transform('browserify-shader');

bundler.bundle()
    .on('error',notifier)
    .pipe( source('main.bundle.js') )//vinyl-source-stream
    // .pipe(buffer())
    // .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true }))
    // .pipe( sourcemaps.write('./'))

    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/js/'));
```

And i do get the sourcemap working to an extent. Breakpoints and logs work in some places, but in some they are wrong pointing to random files and random lines. What am i doing wrong?

## edit

I notice the files/lines change when i mess with the require calls. I had something that wasn't even set up as a module, and most breakpoints were pointing to that. Once i removed that, it's now pointing to another es6 class that has a require, and some logs are even from the shader files.

```
var crossFadeMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({

uniforms:{
    uTexA:{
        type:'t',
        value:null
    },
    uTexB:{
        type:'t',
        value:null
    },
    uFade:{
        type:'f',
        value:0
    }
},
vertexShader: require('./crossFade.vert')(),
fragmentShader: require( './crossFade.frag')()

});


export default class CrossFadePlane extends THREE.Mesh {

constructor(){

    super( pg , crossFadeMaterial.clone() );
    console.log('foo',this);
}
...
```

I get the correct output, but from a completely wrong file (not even the one being required, but coincidentally the same line)

```
vertexShader: require('./crossFade.vert')(),
```

[image: console.log output]

## edit 2

So it's browserify-shader that seems to be messing things up. I removed all the require calls to shaders and the logs are now mapped correctly.